# Change opacity on mouseover in R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I've an absolute Panel in my R shiny app whose and I'm trying to change its opacity depending on mouseover action. If the cursor is on the panel then the opacity will be 1 orelse 0.5

I tried the code below but it makes the panel transparent irrespective of mouseover action

```
                                       fluidPage(
                                         tags$head(tags$style(
                                           HTML('
         #input_date_control {opacity : 0.65;}
         #sel_date {opacity: 1;}')
                                         )),
                                absolutePanel(id = "input_date_control", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                              draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                                              width = 230, height = 213,
                                           
  box(title = 'Selector', width = 11.5, status = 'primary', solidHeader = TRUE,

                                                  tags$head(
                                                    tags$style(
                                                      ".selectize-dropdown, .selectize-input, .selectize-input {
                                                      line-height: 10px;
                                                      }"
  )),

  selectizeInput("disease", label = "Select disease('s)",
                 choices = unique(salmonella_all$Disease), multiple = T,
                 options = list(maxItems = 12, placeholder = 'Select a disease'),
                 selected = "Chlamydia"),
  
  

  
  dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select date range:",
                 start = "2014-01-07",
                 end   = "2017-10-15",
                 min = "2014-01-07",
                 max = "2017-10-15"
                 ))))
```

[The output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYVce.png)

I want to panel to be transparent when theres no mouse over and opaque only when the cursor is over the panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 #sel_date:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
```